# Where do I find a key that JWT is signed with?

Tags: firebase, cryptography, firebase-authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I develop phoenix app that uses Firebase as an external authentication service. I use [Joken](https://github.com/bryanjos/joken) library. It requires me to use function [with_signer](https://hexdocs.pm/joken/Joken.html#with_signer/2) that needs a cryptographic key. I suppose this is the key that JWT was signed with by Firebase. The question is - am I right in my assumptions? And more importantly - where do I find this key?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase should publish a public key at a well known address that you can use to validate the JWTs.

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) suggest:

> Finally, ensure that the ID token was signed by the private key
>   corresponding to the token's kid claim. Grab the public key from
>   https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
>   and use a JWT library to verify the signature. Use the value of
>   max-age in the Cache-Control header of the response from that endpoint
>   to know when to refresh the public keys.

Comment: Don't they rotate their keys?